# Shall I quit trying searching for a postdoc and search for another title in academia?

Tags: research-process, postdocs

I had my PhD in 2004 in computer vision. I have been slow in research since then due to financial commitments and due to working at a non-reasearch university as an assistant prof. I managed to publish 2 papers in ieee conferences. Which means that I have a poor publication record for the number of years I'm in academia.

For the past 3 yrs, I have applied for 7 postdoc posts (but no luck) using an idea that I am passionate about, think is workable and which I have been working on (sometimes slowly).

Now I see myself at a zero-growth situation; I couldn't find a postdoc, & I am not an active research paper generator. Sometimes I think I should apply for a PhD program and get another phd where I can sort of start from scratch. Either way it looks too long of a path to me. Shall I keep doing what I am doing or shall I just quit trying.

Comment: What is your goal in life?

Comment: By and large, survival in academia is based on the "publish or perish" culture. If you don't see yourself capable of publishing at a good consistent rate, I have a hard time seeing how you would be able to survive in academia.

Comment: I am interested to incorporate a flavor of growth in my life. Affiliation with a research environment for a period of time, is one way to facilitate consistent rate of growth (measured for example in publications). Indeed, there could be other spheres for growth. But reading material on math, scientific papers, teaching, .. etc are tools that I have been practicing for many years. That's why I'm looking for research-related growth.

Comment: does your university offer sabbaticals? that might give you a chance to work on research and recharge.

Comment: I totally agree with you, sabbaticals would help. But unfortunately where I work now offer no sabbaticals.

Answer (score 3):

You are in a tough situation, but not hopeless. Just sending out applications is unlikely to work due to your poor record. Instead, you could try to build on your network, start collaborations. If that works you will have polished your record. Now you can also start thinking about applying for funding for a bigger project, requiring a post-doc (you), with your collaborator and use that to move to the research university of your collaborator. So if you want to move into a research university, it is possible, but it is going to be hard work and there is no guarantee of success.

Comment: Yes. Find collaborative opportunities. Write to people with common research interests. Try to get a joint project going. And consider skipping the post-doc step and look for opportunities for regular positions at places that better support research. There are a wide range of institutions between "no research required" and "nothing but research matters". The world isn't binary.